# My DDR3 RAM is not running at its native speed

Tags: memory, ddr3

I upgraded my PC.

Previously I had 2x4GB kingston hyperx 1866MHz.

I then added 2 more sticks of the same type, speed of ram. But now it's only running at 1600MHz which is disappointing. I tried setting the dram voltage(1.5v) and the multiplier(9.33) manually but it wont boot. My processor is an AMD FX-6300.

Comment: XMP is Intel not AMD

Comment: Did you check compatibility with the motherboard/CPU?

Comment: when I use only two sticks the ram runs at full speed 1866mhz

Comment: https://www.gigabyte.com/ph/Motherboard/GA-970A-DS3P-rev-2x/sp#sp yes it does support 4x1866,

Answer (score 1):

Please check, that your memory configuration is such that your two new modules are in one memory channel (i.e. Channel A) and your two existing modules are in another channel (i.e. Channel B)

Another thing you may try is switching the memory pairs around. That is, move the modules currently in Channel A to Channel B and vice versa to see if that improves the memory detection.

Taken from [the manual](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-970a-ds3p_v.2.x_e.pdf):

Dual Channel Memory Configuration

This motherboard provides four DDR3 memory sockets and supports Dual Channel Technology. After the memory is installed, the BIOS will automatically detect the specifications and capacity of the memory. Enabling Dual Channel memory mode will double the original memory bandwidth.

The four DDR3 memory sockets are divided into two channels and each channel has two memory sockets as following:

- Channel A: DDR3_2, DDR3_4
- Channel B: DDR3_1, DDR3_3

Due to CPU limitations, read the following guidelines before installing the memory in Dual Channel mode.

1. Dual Channel mode cannot be enabled if only one DDR3 memory module is installed.
2. When enabling Dual Channel mode with two or four memory modules, it is recommended that memory of the same capacity, brand, speed, and chips be used and installed in the same colored DDR3 sockets for optimum performance. For optimum performance, when enabling Dual Channel mode with two memory modules, we recommend that you install them in the DDR3_1 and DDR3_2 sockets.